# OSB sbconfig.jar issue - JVM Char length Issue

Tags: jvm, char, osb

I am working on an Oracle OSB Build job using Jenkins.

```
The issue I am facing is: In the sbconfig.jar that's gets crated is not having the full service name.
 Ex. If my OSB service name is EmployeeRecordDetailReturnsStorageBOService but in the sbconfig.jar its getting created as EmployeeRecordDetailReturnsStorageBOSer only.

      I need the full service name in the sbconfig.jar for my further processing of this jar.
 I am using the eclipse based jar <java dir="${eclipse.home}" jar="${eclipse.home}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar" ...> in my ant build file.

 But what I have observed is the java command that we are using has a folder length limit. It could not created the full service name in the sbconfig.jar because the ant build file is in a deep location under the folders like abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/xyz/build.xml so thats why its not able to create the full service name in the sbconfig.jar file. Its seems to be an character length issue in java/JVM.

Can anybody pls let me know how to to over some this problem.
```

Comment: Four spaces in front of a line tell StackOverflow that the line represents code. You should remove these spaces in front of your text.

Comment: Please learn how to use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) formatting correctly. The indentation you added you original post means that it has been treated as unformatted text, and some of the special characters caused parts to not be displayed at all.   To the right of the question and answer editbox on Stackoverflow is a question-mark icon which provides some hints to get you started, and below is a WYSIWYG view.

Answer (score 0):

It will not cause any issue when you will be importing the sbconfig.jar back into the sbconsole. So, do not worry about name getting shortened in sbconfig.jar.

If you are facing any issue while importing then let us know.